# list comprehensions in a nested list

Tags: python, string, nested-lists

I have two lists

```
onnet_data = [['one', 'test'], ['two', 'test2'], ['three', 'test3'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
elastic_data = [['one', 'test'], ['three', 'test3'], ['six', 'test6'], ['seven', 'test7']]
```

I am trying to compare first elements in sublists of onnet_data and elastic_data. I want to takeout the data from onnet_data if it matches, as common_data and later find the remaining list items in onnet_data.

```
onnet = [onnet_data[i][0] for i in range(len(onnet_data))]
elastic = [elastic_data[i][0] for i in range(len(elastic_data))]

common = list(set(onnet)& set(elastic))
common_data = []
for i in range(len(common)):
    for j in range(len(onnet_data)):
        if common[i] == onnet_data[j][0]:
            common_data.append(onnet_data[j])
```

I tried like

```
from operator import ne
from functools import partial
onnet_remaining = list(filter(partial(ne, common_data), onnet_data))
```

expected output of onnet_remaining is

```
[['two', 'test2'],  ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
```

but it prints everything of onnet_data. I am not able to use list(set(onnet_data) - set(common_data)) as it is nested list.

is there any way ? is there any other easy way as my data 
 is with len(onnet_data)=69973 and len(elastic_data)=107730

update: based on the answer from roadrunner, the list is bit different.

```
onnet_data = [['one', 'test'], ['two', 'test2'], ['three', 'test3'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
elastic_data = [['one', 'something'], ['three', 'some3'], ['six', 'some6'], ['seven', 'some7']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension here:

```
>>> [x for x in onnet_data if x not in elastic_data]
[['two', 'test2'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
```

However, list lookups are **O(N)** using `in` and can be expensive for longer lists. You can convert `elastic_data` to a set of tuples(lists are not hashable) to get **O(1)** lookups:

```
>>> lookup = set(map(tuple, elastic_data))
>>> [x for x in onnet_data if tuple(x) not in lookup]
[['two', 'test2'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
```

As updated in the question, if you want to compare the first element in each sublist, you can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in onnet_data if not any(z == x for z, _ in elastic_data)]
[['two', 'test2'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
```

And you can use sets also here to get **O(1)** lookups, since using `any()` is **O(N)**:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lookup = set(map(itemgetter(0), elastic_data))
>>> [[x, y] for x, y in onnet_data if x not in lookup]
[['two', 'test2'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a list comprehension:

```
from operator import itemgetter

onnet_data = [['one', 'test'], ['two', 'test2'], ['three', 'test3'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
elastic_data = [['one', 'test'], ['three', 'test3'], ['six', 'test6'], ['seven', 'test7']]

onnet_remaining = [datum for datum in onnet_data if datum[0] not in map(itemgetter(0), elastic_data)]
```

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
onnet_data = [['one', 'test'], ['two', 'test2'], ['three', 'test3'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
elastic_data = [['one', 'test'], ['three', 'test3'], ['six', 'test6'], ['seven', 'test7']]

filtered_list = [string for string in onnet_data if string not in elastic_data]  
print("filtered list:", filtered_list)
```

output:

```
filtered list: [['two', 'test2'], ['four', 'test4'], ['five', 'test5']]
```